# How to make yattag source better formatted?

Tags: html, python-3.x, line-breaks, yattag

I'm using `yattag` to generate HTML:

```
doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()

with tag("p"):
    text("My paragraph.")
```

While it works well enough, when I look at the HTML source it comes out all on one line. Is there some kind of switch or other trick that makes `yattag` create more readable source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`indent`](http://www.yattag.org/#indentation) function.

```
from yattag import Doc, indent

doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()

with tag("p"):
    text("My paragraph.")

print(indent(doc.getvalue())) # will indent the tags but not the text directly contained between <tag> and </tag>

print(indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text = True)) # will also indent the text directly contained between <tag> and </tag>
```